# Flex Individual image loading

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image, loader

I want to know if anyone can point me in the right direction for individually loading images (I think thats what is happening) in Flex 4.

I saw [this site](http://www.homestyler.com/designer) and I like the way each individual picture gets loaded when a new category is opened and thought it would be very useful in our next project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SWFLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) component to point a URL, and load your images runtime. Could you clarify more your question?